# link error compiling qt project on visual 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, qt, compilation

i try to compile a qt project with visual 2010, but i have some link error when i rebuilt my solution :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall BNetwork::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" on bnetwork.obj
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall Contact::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" on contact.obj
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall BNetwork::metaObject(void)const " on bnetwork.obj  
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall Contact::metaObject(void)const " on contact.obj
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall BNetwork::qt_metacast(char const *)" on bnetwork.obj
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall Contact::qt_metacast(char const *)" on contact.obj
```

after some "googlize" i don't find some solution about this problem so 
i put all of my Qt libs on c:/QT/4.7.4/lib/ on my project's additional dependencies, but i always have these errors...

i'm sure that Qt is build and install on visual because when i compile this following code (it's an exemple, not my project) it works fine :

```
#include <QtGui/qapplication.h>
#include <QtGui/qpushButton.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QPushButton bouton("Bonjour les Zéros !");
    bouton.show();

    QObject::connect(&bouton, SIGNAL(clicked()), &app, SLOT(quit()));

    return app.exec();
}
```

i haven't these errors so i think it's specific to my project but i don't find a solution

Anyone can help me plz ?

Comment: yeah i build qt with nmake (= 4h) and install the Qt add-in on visual. i edit my post

Comment: Problem solved ! i do `moc -I"%QTDIR%\include" -I"%QTDIR%\include\QtCore" -I"%QTDIR%\include\QtGui" -omoc_contact.cpp contact.h` and the same on `bnetwork.h`. after this i add the new .cpp files on my project and it works !

Comment: Glad to hear that. Post and accept your answer :)

Comment: i can't, i don't have the reputation level. can you post a msg plz ?

Comment: @Yumino You should not really do it by hand, take a look at qmake.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem solved ! i do moc -I"%QTDIR%\include"
>   -I"%QTDIR%\include\QtCore" -I"%QTDIR%\include\QtGui" -omoc_contact.cpp contact.h and the same on bnetwork.h. after this i add the new .cpp
>   files on my project and it works ! Thanks to @Yumino :)